# Concerning the noncompactness of the map, $I: W^{1, 2}(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow L^{2^{\ast}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Consider the identity map $I:W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R^n})\rightarrow L^{2^{\ast}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $n\geq 3$. Suppose that this map is not compact that is given some bounded sequence of functions $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}\subset W^{1, 2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ there is no subsequence that converges strongly to some $f$ with respect to the $L^{2^{\ast}}$ norm. So $f_k\nrightarrow f \text{ strongly in } L^{2^{\ast}}$.

So for some subsequence $\{f_{k_j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}\subset \{f_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ we can deduce that
\begin{equation}
f_{k_j}\rightharpoonup f \text{ in } L_{\text{loc}}^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n),\quad Df_{k_j}\rightharpoonup Df \text{ in } L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)
\end{equation} 
since $W^{1, 2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is reflexive.

Is it possible to show that:

1. $f_{k_j}\rightarrow f$ strongly in $L_{\text{loc}}^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
2. $\vert Df_{k_j}\vert^2\rightharpoonup \mu\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
3. $\vert f_{k_j}\vert^{2^{\ast}}\rightharpoonup \nu\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

where $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of signed Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finite mass?

Comment: What is $L^{2^\ast}$?

Comment: This is the set\begin{equation} L^{2^{\ast}}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\left\{f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ \vert\ f\text{ is measurable wrt Lesbegue n-dim. measure and } \left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \vert f(x)\vert^{2^{\ast}}\text{ d}x\right]^{1/2^{\ast}}<\infty \right\}\end{equation} where \begin{equation} 2^{\ast}\equiv\frac{2n}{n-2}.\end{equation}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a few things here need straightening out.

> Suppose that this map is not compact

This is not something we suppose. It is a  fact that $I$ is not compact.

> given any bounded sequence of functions $\{f_k\}^\infty_{k=1}\subset W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^n)$ there is no subsequence that converges strongly

This is not what "not compact" means. In this context, "compact" means "for any bounded sequence there is a subsequence that converges". The negation of "compact" is "there exists a bounded sequence for which there is no subsequence that converges".

> We can deduce that

No, we cannot. We can deduce weak convergence for a subsequence of $f_k$, not for $f_k$ themselves.

Now to your questions:

1. $L^2_{\rm loc}$ is not a normed space, so   "strongly in $L^2_{\rm loc}$" is not a precise statement. Presumably you meant "strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$ for every bounded domain $\Omega$." Then it's true by Rellich-Kondrachov (since $2<2^*$) but not for the entire sequence - only for a subsequence.
2. and 3. The answer is yes - again, only for a subsequence - by virtue of weak* compactness of closed balls in the space of finite measures, considered as the dual of $C_0(\mathbb R^n)$. All you need from $f_k$ here is that $\int |Df_k|^2$ and $\int |f|^{2^*}$ are uniformly bounded; the first is true by assumption, the second by the Sobolev embedding.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed a couple of the things in my question which you said. It is a fact that $I$ is not compact but I am working on a characterisation of this noncompactness right now and so I've left the word 'suppose' to remind/emphasize the direction of the iff proof I'm trying to prove. My wrong negation of compactness made the actual stuff that I wanted to do with this information harder. But things are more straightforward now and getting the above results for a subsequence is sufficient. Cheers.